# What should I do if I want to autofill password in others app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, autofill, password-autofill

I created an APP that have AutoFill extension，it can run on the website and autofill my password. But I can't autofill in others App，it will crash..thanks for helping

for example, when I open others App such as Facebook,and run my app,which I want to autofill , my app will crash, why?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the exception message?  What is the code it crashes on?

Comment: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is 'unknown' in '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BB48E7EC-FC4D-4992-B628-25B688798F86/Mobile01.app/Mobile01'

Comment: the app just flash out and do nothing it didnt crash actually